# R: read in multiple .xlxs files from AWS S3

Tags: r, loops, amazon-s3, readxl

I am quite new to R and I have a problem which I think needs solving by a loop...

I have multiple .xlsx files in AWS S3:

(note the naming of each do not follow a pattern)

- File name 1: climate_change.xlsx
- File name 2: farming.xlsx
- etc etc

Each file is identical in structure but contains very messy data . Once each file is read into R, I have the same code to tidy each file.

**What I would like to be able to do:**

Within a loop:

- Read in file 1, apply the tidying code...
- Read in file 2, apply the tidying code...
- etc etc

Then once we have looped through each file (reading and tidying) rbind each of the tidied files together.

**What I have already:**

All files are in the same AWS folder. The code I have to read in a single file from that folder is here:

```
data <- aws.s3::s3read_using(
                            FUN = readxl::read_xlsx,
                            object = "folder/climate_change.xlsx",
                            bucket = s3_bucket,
                            sheet = "sheet1")
```

I have some code for tidying which works on each single file.

I also have a .csv lookup which I can read in with each of the file names:

| file_name |
| --- |
| climate_change.xlsx |
| farming.xlsx |

How would I create the loop?

Comment: If you have a list of the filenames/file paths you could then use `lapply()` to read each of the files at once.

Answer (score 0):

As @wernor suggests, this is the general approach you need, in pseudocode, since you haven't provided a MWE.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

fileList <- myCSVLookup()

allMyData <- lapply(
               fileList,
               function(f) {
                 aws.s3::s3read_using(
                   FUN = readxl::read_xlsx,
                   object = f,
                   bucket = s3_bucket,
                   sheet = "sheet1"
                 ) %>% 
                 myTidyFunction()
               }
            ) %>% 
            bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thanks both - I am looking for bind rows as the data within each .xlsx is report data on each programme -- same reporting measures for each programme.

@Limey - note your point on lack of MWE - thanks for presenting a solution despite this.  For this to work, would fileList need to be a list of the .xlsx names?

Comment: Oh, okay, my bad for assuming. About `fileList`, it could be an array, it doesn't need to be a list. You probably would need filepaths though if you are working on a different folder.